# How to create method which get two parameters - stream and integer

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I need to implement the method that takes a Stream and integer and returns the list of Strings. The list should be grouped according to int numbers - ordered of highest to lowest and return only numbers

I want to do it in one stream and get something like this:

```
public static List<String> groupFunc(Stream<Nums> nums, int pass) {       
  List<Object> myList = nums.filter(s-> s.getScore() >= pass).sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}


List<Nums> nums = new ArrayList<Nums>();

        nums.add(new Nums("A", 80));
        nums.add(new Nums("B", 57));
        nums.add(new Nums("C", 21));

        groupFunc(nums.stream(), 50).forEach(System.out::println);

    // should print "A","B"
```

Could you help me with this stream? I don't know if I should use filter+soreted. Or maybe foreach? This `Comparator.naturalOrder` is just temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utility methods in interface [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) are very useful to help with these types of operations:

```
public static List<String> groupFunc(Stream<Nums> nums, int pass) {
    return nums
            .filter(s-> s.getScore() >= pass)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Nums::getScore).reversed())
            .map(Nums::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```